# Detect whether a specific part of body collided with another body in box2d

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

Kindly suggest some explanation or code regarding how can i detect **collision between a specific part of one body with another body** in box2d with libgdx.I am able to detect simple collision between two bodies using Contact Listener as mentioned [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#contact-listeners)But I also want to check **which part of bodies are ovelapping**.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `ContactListener` provides you with `Contact` as a callback parameter. Those contacts will tell you which `Fixtures` did collide via `contact.getFixtureA()` and `contact.getFixtureB()`.

What people usually do to find out which part of their bodies collided, is to build them with several `Fixtures` via `body.createFixture(...)`.

You can set user data on `Fixture` as well as on `Body` with `fixture.setUserData()` and `body.setUserData()`. You could either save your fixture somewhere else and compare via `contact.getFixtureA() == xxx.savedFixture`.

That might be in your entity for example like the following:

```
public class Player {
    public Fixture arm;

    // create the player body and store the arm fixture
    body.setUserData(this);
    arm = body.createFixture(...);
}
```

Then later you can do this in your contact listener:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    if (contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData().getClass().equals(Player.class)) {
        if (contact.getFixtureA() == ((Player)contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData()).arm == contact.getFixtureA()) {
            // the arm collided with something
        }
    }
}
```

Or you might just add some user data like `fixture.setUserData("arm")` which you can then easily check. In your contact callback handler.

Comment: and i didnt got what are you trying to explain by saving fixture somewhere.?

Comment: UserData can be anything. It's an `Object`. It is what you want it to be. You can save your fixture somewhere in your entity as a field.

Comment: @JigarPandya I gave you some more pseudo code to show how you can use the user data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how to build part of body to check whether it is colliding with other bodies??

Comment: Um, I thought that's what I described in my answer... with several `body.createFixture(...)`

Comment: Maybe you should re-read my whole answer, try to understand the ideas behind it and then just try it yourself in your particular scenario? My answer is already much longer than your initial question and without any more specific details to your problem, I can't help you anymore at this point.

Comment: @JigarPandya UserData is just a property of fixtures which you can set to anything you want. For example you can set it to a string, and then later use that string to identify the fixture by using GetUserData().