# How to find if top of rectangle collided or not in box2d

Tags: box2d, box2dweb

I have rectangular player in top down game. I want to find which side(to be specific top of rectangle ) of rectangle is hit by other game objects.

Comment: please share your part of code for better understanding

Comment: I am new to box2d. So currently i have a simple rectangular fixture. And checking collision with Begincontact listener.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203687/box2d-how-to-detect-which-side-of-a-polygon-gets-collision

Comment: Thanks. i will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to distinguish between collisions for different parts of your game object, use different fixtures for those parts. So if you want to distinguish between top and bottom for example:

```
-----------------
|               |
|Top Fixture    |
|               |
-----------------
|               |
|Bottom Fixture |
|               |
-----------------
```

These could also be sensors (so no physics) as an overlay for your other physics fixtures.

Comment: I did the same way using different fixture without sensor and that worked well. With sensor other object will penetrate sensor and collide with other part of player resulting in multiple contacts.

Comment: Cool. Ya you can tweak things with collision filters, but if you got it working then ace :)